# TI ARM with stacked RAM

Tags: arm-cpu

Do any of the TI [ARM SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_system-on-chip_architecture)s, e.g. [OMAP](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/arm/sitara_arm_cortex_a_processor/sitara_arm_cortex_a8/omap3503_15_arm_cortex_a8/products.page?paramCriteria=no) or [Da Vinci](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/dsp/video_processors/overview.page), have a version with stacked RAM? (e.g. DDR2 or mDDR) For miniature robots like micro drones, it would be really nice to not need to spend board area on an external RAM chip. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to TI's website, [some of the OMAP processors (specifically the OMAP-DM5x range) have stacked RAM](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?templateId=6123&navigationId=12828&contentId=50020).

[image: chip architecture]

More info [here (PDF)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swpt036/swpt036.pdf).